# Combining Cumulative Binomial Probabilities? with simple change in probability?

Tags: binomial-distribution

Greg can hit a free throw 85% of the time.
Greg can hit a three-pointer 45% of the time.

Greg enters a contest that involves shooting 15 free throws and 5 three-pointers.
Each attempt is either a basket or a miss.

What is the probability Greg makes 12 baskets total?

---

Easy if just free-throws or just three-pointers, but how do you combine the two?

Comment: Bueller? Anyone?  What an easier problem so I can see the logic anyway...  The contest is 15 free throws and only 1 three-pointer.  So 15 @ 85% for the cumulative binomial probability (easy) and then one more chance at 45%.  Do I just multiply the 15@85% results by 0.45?   I feel like I'm being dense, but am getting lost.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Should say "What about an easier problem..."  Won't let me edit after five minutes.  And sorry for the formatting jumble...can't figure out how to add line breaks.  Help said double spaces, but that didn't work and can't hit enter to get one.